# Complex type convention by property name?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**Complex Type**

```
public class Timestamp
{
    public string By { get; set; }
    public DateTime? On { get; set; }
}
```

**Desired Default Mapping**

Is there a way to add conventions to entity framework so that types that have my `Timestamp` class as a property (like below) default map to "CreatedBy" instead of "Created_By"? If so, how?

```
public class StationProductRun
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlantProductRunId { get; set; }
    public int StationId { get; set; }
    public string SapProductId { get; set; }
    public Timestamp Created { get; set; }
    public Timestamp Started { get; set; }
    public Timestamp Finished { get; set; }

    public StationProductRun()
    {
        Created = new Timestamp();
        Started = new Timestamp();
        Finished = new Timestamp();
    }
}
```

- Created.By => CreatedBy
- Created.On => CreatedOn
- Started.By => StartedBy
- Started.On => StartedOn
- Finished.By => FinishedBy
- Etc.

I know I could create `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` implementations for each type, but I'm getting sick and tired of writing such scaffoldable code and seek a better alternative.

**What I've Tried**

I tried the following, but I'm not sure if I'm even in the ballpark on this one and  it complains about filtering out properties and such. Not even sure this does what I want.

```
modelBuilder.Properties<Timestamp>()
            .Configure(x =>
            {
                if (x.ClrPropertyInfo.DeclaringType == typeof(Timestamp))
                {
                    switch (x.ClrPropertyInfo.Name)
                    {
                        case "By":
                            x.HasColumnName(x.ClrPropertyInfo.Name + "By")
                             .IsOptional();
                            return;
                        case "On":
                            x.HasColumnName(x.ClrPropertyInfo.Name + "On")
                             .IsOptional();
                            return;
                    }
                }
            });
```

> 'The type 'Timestamp' cannot be used to filter properties. Only scalar types, string, and byte[] are supported.'

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will be using until I get an answer. It's not my ideal solution, but it's better than what I currently have.

**Entity Interfaces**

```
public interface ICreated
{
    Timestamp Created { get; set; }
}

public interface IModified
{
    Timestamp Modified { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity Type Configurations**

```
public class EntityConfigCreated<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : class, ICreated
{
    public EntityConfigCreated()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.Created.By)
            .HasColumnName("CreatedBy")
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .IsOptional();

        this.Property(x => x.Created.On)
            .HasColumnName("CreatedOn")
            .IsOptional();
    }
}

public class EntityConfigModified<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : class, IModified
{
    public EntityConfigModified()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.Modified.By)
            .HasColumnName("ModifiedBy")
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .IsOptional();

        this.Property(x => x.Modified.On)
            .HasColumnName("ModifiedOn")
            .IsOptional();
    }
}

public class EntityConfigCreatedModified<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : class, ICreated, IModified
{
    public EntityConfigCreatedModified()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.Created.By)
            .HasColumnName("CreatedBy")
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .IsOptional();

        this.Property(x => x.Created.On)
            .HasColumnName("CreatedOn")
            .IsOptional();

        this.Property(x => x.Modified.By)
            .HasColumnName("ModifiedBy")
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .IsOptional();

        this.Property(x => x.Modified.On)
            .HasColumnName("ModifiedOn")
            .IsOptional();
    }
}
```

This way I don't have to implement `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` for each type, just each combination of timestamp properties. Which most have just `Created` and `Modified` so it's a significant reduction in coding, still not a good as using the declared property as the naming scheme though.